# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que una función me return 1 o 0?

Tags: c#

Buenos días,antes que nada agradezco la ayuda que me han dado; debo hacer este ejercicio;

> En la facultad de Sistemas de la Universidad de Carolina, se quiere
>   conformar al equipo representativo juvenil varonil de Básquetbol para
>   las olimpiadas intrauniversitarias, para esto se tiene los registros
>   con las características físicas de los n alumnos de la facultad y se
>   desea conocer la lista de los alumnos con aptitudes para practicar y
>   formar parte del equipo representativo de Básquetbol. Desarrollar un
>   programa por medio de funciones para obtener: la lista de alumnos con
>   aptitudes físicas con una altura mayor o igual a 183 centímetros y un
>   peso entre 73 y 110 kilos y la edad entre 15 y 18 años. Para cada
>   alumno se ingresa su nombre, sexo, edad, peso y altura. Mostrar en
>   pantalla a cada alumno (Nombre, Sexo, Edad, Peso y Altura), que
>   cumplen con estos requerimientos. El programa deberá tener una función
>   llamada apto que recibirá los parámetros tipo entero altura, peso,
>   edad y una tipo carácter, sexo. Si los requisitos se cumplen deberá
>   retornar 1, en caso contrario deberá retornar 0. Si el valor retornado
>   es 1, se mostrará el mensaje identificando al alumno como apto.

En este momento estoy creando la función , pero luego de hacer la condición , no entiendo muy bien como usar un dato bool , este es el código de la función (no puse el del main, el meain solo le la cantidad de estudiantes y envia el valor a valorcantidadestudiantes):

```
class Program
{
    static bool apto(int valorcantidadestudiantes, int altura, int peso, int edad )
    {
        int i;
        bool resultado;
        for (i = 0; i < valorcantidadestudiantes; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ingrese edad del estudiante:");
            edad = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("ingrese altura del estudiante:");
            altura = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("ingrese peso del estudiante:");
            peso = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if(edad>15 && edad<18 && altura>=183 && peso>73 && peso<110)
            {
                resultado = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                resultado = 0;
            }



        }
        return resultado;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas Jorge,

Los datos tipo `bool` sólo pueden ser `True` o `False`, no pueden ser números, por lo tanto, si la función debe retornar `0` o `1` la función debería ser `int` en vez de `bool`:

```
static int apto(int valorcantidadestudiantes, int altura, int peso, int edad )
{
    int i;
    int resultado;
    ** Código **
    return resultado;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando te mencionan que existirá una función `apto` al que se le pasan como parámetros `altura`, `peso`, `edad` y `sexo` significa que estos valores ya los has obtenido previamente, posiblemente en la función que llama a `apto()` por lo que no debes de llamar ni a `Console.WriteLine` ni a `Console.ReadLine` ahí. Además esta función deveulve un valor 1 o 0, no un `bool` sino un `int`

La función deberá quedar algo así

```
static int Apto(int altura, int peso, int edad, char sexo)
{
    return altura >= 183 &&
        peso >= 73 && peso <= 110 &&
        edad >= 15 && edad <= 18 &&
        sexo == 'M' ?
            1 :
            0;
}
```

Luego esta función deberá ser llamado desde `Main()`, las llamadas a `Console.WriteLine` y `Console.ReadLine` te servirán para obtener los valores de los parámetros a pasarle al método `Apto()` y el valor de retorno te servirá para hacer un `if` y decidir si mostrar o o el mensaje "Apto".

El código de `Main` te lo dejo a tí.